# Email Scope missing in Identity Server 4 even when added to Client

Tags: identityserver4

I am using Identity Server 4 with an Angular client.

In both sides I am adding the same scopes:

```
'openid profile offline_access email api'
```

However I get an error:

```
Sorry, there was an error : invalid_scope
Invalid scope
```

I checked the Well-Known OpenID configuration and I see:

```
"scopes_supported": [
  "openid",
  "profile",
  "api",
  "offline_access"
```

]

So the email scope does not show?

Might this be the problem? Why does this happen?

My Identity Server 4 Client definition is:

```
new Client {

  ClientId = "spa",
  ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
  AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
  RequirePkce = true,
  RequireClientSecret = false,
  AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
  AllowOfflineAccess = true,

  AllowedScopes = { 
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile, 
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email, 
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
    "api" 
  },  

  RedirectUris = new List<String> { 
    "https://localhost:5001",
    "https://localhost:5001/index.html",
    "https://localhost:5001/silent-refresh.html" 
  },

  PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<String> { 
    "https://localhost:5001/" 
  },

  AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<String> { 
    "https://localhost:5001" 
  }

}
```

Comment: Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579376/identityserver4-how-to-access-user-email

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add an IdentityResource:

```
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            new IdentityResources.Email()
        };
    }
```

Then in startup.cs add this:

```
var identityServerBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer(...)
.AddInMemoryIdentityResources(GetIdentityResources())
```